# Ionic - Force refresh animation from controller

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Anyone knows if there is a way to trigger the refresh animation from ion-refresher from the controller?

I want to start the page with refresher spinning

I have tried simulating the pull action with `$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom()` and also by setting a `delegate-handle` in the refresher and the calling the scroll from there `$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('scroll').scrollBottom()` with no success.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally created my own directive for this
I'm sharing it if someone is looking to achieve the the same

**loadingDirective.js**

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('loadingDirective', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  'use strict';

  var loadingTemplate = '<div class="loading-directive"><i class="icon ion-loading-d" /></div>';

  var _linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html(loadingTemplate);
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);

    scope.$on('loading.hide', function() {
      element.addClass('closing');
    });
    scope.$on('loading.show', function() {
      element.removeClass('closing');
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: _linker,
    scope: {
      content: '='
    }
  };
}]);
```

**loadingDirective.sass**

```
loading-directive {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: $scroll-refresh-icon-color;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;

  height: 60px;
  display: block;


  @include transition(height, padding .2s);

  .loading-directive {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform: scale(1,1);

    @include transition(transform .2s);
    @include transition(-webkit-transform .2s);
  }

  &.closing {
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    .loading-directive {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
      transform: scale(0,0);
    }
  }

  i {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
}
```

To use it in a template, just add `<loading-directive>` tag at the beggining of the content:

**template.html**

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
    <loading-directive></loading-directive>
    <ion-refresher ng-if="refresherActive" pulling-text="Pull to refresh" on-refresh="refreshData()">
    <ion-list></ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The loading will be shown when the view is loaded until the close event is fired
From the controller, `$scope.$broadcast('loading.hide')` will close the loading icon and `$scope.$broadcast('loading.show')` will show it again

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the `ion-spinner` directive directly. Ionic's pull-to-refresh shows the `ion-spinner` directive after you pull down.

HTML:

```
<ion-spinner ng-if="isLoading"></ion-spinner>
```

JS:

(in your controller...)

```
$scope.isLoading = true;

myFetchDataFunction().then(function() {
  $scope.isLoading = false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to trigger the refresh with Ionic's API. The refresh component works by scrolling beyond the scroll area (which starts to expose the refresher), which is something the user has to do when they pull down.

Your best bet is to show the loading is happening with some other interface component.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I finally created a custom directive. I posted the code below if someone has the same problem